Проблема с Advanced Installer 22.1
Вопрос касательно Advanced Installer. Как создать кастомное окно с дополнительной обработкой? Я хочу, чтобы пользователь ввел там пароль, нажал на кнопку, и данные отправились в программу.
Возможно ли реализовать отправку данных в приложение, написанное на Python?
